# Facebook C# Iframe Authorization

Tags: authentication, jquery, facebook-c#-sdk

I have an IFrame Facebook application that uses Facebook C# SDK. I also use jquery and load some page components asynchronously. For example, I call the following javascript from main page(at this point user is authenticated)

```
$.ajax({            
    type: "POST",
    url: "Ajax/GetMyBalance.aspx",        
    datatype: 'text',
    success: function (html) {
        $('#balance_div').html(html);
    }
    });
```

The problem is that in `GetMyBalance.aspx:PageLoad` the user is not authenticated. I tried adding

```
 FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp();
 CanvasAuthorizer auth = new CanvasAuthorizer(app);
 if (!auth.IsAuthorized()) // always true when page is loaded first time
 {
    var url = auth.GetLoginUrl(new HttpRequestWrapper(Request));
    var content = CanvasUrlBuilder.GetCanvasRedirectHtml(url);
    Response.ContentType = "text/html";
    Response.Write(content);
    Response.End();
 }
```

to `GetMyBalance.aspx:PageLoad` ; it did authenticate the user, but it also redirected browser to `Myapp/Ajax/GetMyBalance.aspx` which might make sense, but it's absolutely not what I wanted. How can I authenticate user in this case ? 
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with no cookies.  Set cookieSupport = false in the SDK settings and initialize the Javascript client library with cookie=false.  Then get the auth token using the Javascript client library before you post, pass the auth token up to the server, and use it to instantiate your FacebookApp instance.

```
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
          if (response.session) {
            $('#AuthToken').val(response.session.access_token);
            $('form').ajaxSubmit(options);
            return false;
          } else {
            // not logged in, prompt them to retry
            return false;
          }
        }, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enabling cookie support in facebookSettings?

```
<facebookSettings apiKey="blah" apiSecret="blah" appId="blah" cookieSupport="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about it.

Comment: It works, but I just wonder if there is other way to do it? I have  problems with Safari that doesn't like when parent sets cookies for iframe.

Comment: Is this cookie being set by the Facebook JS SDK? The c# is running in the context of the iframe so that shouldn't present a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, cookieSupport does not seem to be a valid property:

"Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'cookieSupport'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive."

--- update ---

My apologies, I found this:
http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/releases/view/59012

At SDK 4.2.1 cookieSupport is automatic, that is why I got the error